# "this" is become undefined in ngOnDestroy angular 12

Tags: angular12

```
ngOnDestroy() {
 if (this.subscription) {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```

I am trying to unsubscribe subscription in ngOnDestroy() but "this" is coming undefined.

core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscription')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscription')

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzdO8.png)